# Check if a string has white space

Tags: javascript, whitespace

I'm trying to **check if a string has white space**. I found this function but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) 
{
    var reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("/^\s+$/");

    // Check for white space
    if (reWhiteSpace.test(s)) {
        //alert("Please Check Your Fields For Spaces");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

By the way, I added quotes to `RegExp`.

Is there something wrong? Is there anything better that I can use? Hopefully JQuery.

Comment: your logic is backwards, true means false.

Comment: You're returning false if the string has whitespace, your logic is backwards

Comment: That regex in question checks for patterns with only whitespaces in strings, starts with whitespace, has one or more whitespace, and ends with a whitespace.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

You can simply use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) method on the input string:

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

Or you can use the test method, on a simple RegEx:

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}
```

This will also check for other white space characters like Tab.

Comment: couldn't you put in s.indexOf(/^\s+$/) as well?

Comment: this is not supported by IE8 (just a friendly fyi...)

Comment: @CMS& @Bernard - Does not work [s.indexOf(' ') works]

Comment: @BernardChen it does work now in 2022...see this link and the explanation on the right hand side within this link: https://regex101.com/r/35I65w/1

Answer (score 37):

Your regex won't match anything, as it is. You definitely need to remove the quotes -- the `"/"` characters are sufficient.

`/^\s+$/` is checking whether the string is *ALL* whitespace:

- `^` matches the start of the string.
- `\s+` means at least 1, possibly more, spaces.
- `$` matches the end of the string.

Try replacing the regex with `/\s/` (and no quotes)

Answer (score 11):

The `test` method is the best way to go. The character class `\s` checks for any whitespace character including space, tab, carriage return and form feed.

The global flag is not necessary since we are looking for a single match. Regex literals run faster than their constructor equivalents because they are better optimized by the runtime.

```js
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return (/\s/).test(s);
}

console.log(hasWhiteSpace("Hello World!"));
console.log(hasWhiteSpace("HelloWorld!"));

console.time('hasWhiteSpace');
for (let i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
  hasWhiteSpace("Some text here");
}
console.timeEnd('hasWhiteSpace');
```

If you are working with certain whitespace characters only, you can take advantage of array methods like `some` which returns on first successful match but they will be slower than the regex's test method:

```js
// Use includes method on string
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  const whitespaceChars = [' ', '\t', '\n'];
  return whitespaceChars.some(char => s.includes(char));
}

console.log(hasWhiteSpace("Hello World!"));
console.log(hasWhiteSpace("HelloWorld!"));

console.time('hasWhiteSpace');
for (let i = 0; i < 1_000_000; i++) {
  hasWhiteSpace("Some text here");
}
console.timeEnd('hasWhiteSpace');
```

As you see in the performance benchmarks, the `test` method is slightly faster than `some` method which won't be noticeable anyway.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using ECMAScript6 (ES6) or newer, the easiest method that will do the magic is show below

```
// looking just for spaces   
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.includes(' ');
}
```

Above function have a couple of limitations,

- It just match the white space but no other possible whitespace
  characters as tab or line break.
- It doesn't support Regex.

If We need to use a Regex to match all possible whitespace characters, We can use `search` option that is available since ECMAScript1 (ES1):

```
// looking for spaces, tabs, line breakers, etc. 
// live example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.search(/\s/);
}

// looking just for spaces, equivalent to includes option
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.search(/ /);
}
```

This will also check for other white space characters like Tab.

Answer (score 4):

A few others have posted answers.  There are some obvious problems, like it returns `false` when the Regex passes, and the `^` and `$` operators indicate start/end, whereas the question is looking for has (any) whitespace, and not: only contains whitespace (which the regex is checking).

*Besides that, the issue is just a typo.*

Change this...

```
var reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("/^\s+$/");
```

To this...

```
var reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("\\s+");
```

When using a regex within `RegExp()`, you must do the two following things...

- Omit starting and ending `/` brackets.
- Double-escape all sequences code, i.e., `\\s` in place of `\s`, etc.

***Full working demo from source code....***

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) { function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
        var reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("\\s+");
    
        // Check for white space
        if (reWhiteSpace.test(s)) {
            //alert("Please Check Your Fields For Spaces");
            return 'true';
        }
    
        return 'false';
    }
  
  $('#whitespace1').html(hasWhiteSpace(' '));
  $('#whitespace2').html(hasWhiteSpace('123'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
" ": <span id="whitespace1"></span><br>
"123": <span id="whitespace2"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

This function checks for other types of whitespace, not just space (tab, carriage return, etc.)

```
import some from 'lodash/fp/some'
const whitespaceCharacters = [' ', '  ',
  '\b', '\t', '\n', '\v', '\f', '\r', `\"`, `\'`, `\\`,
  '\u0008', '\u0009', '\u000A', '\u000B', '\u000C',
'\u000D', '\u0020','\u0022', '\u0027', '\u005C',
'\u00A0', '\u2028', '\u2029', '\uFEFF']
const hasWhitespace = char => some(
  w => char.indexOf(w) > -1,
  whitespaceCharacters
)

console.log(hasWhitespace('a')); // a, false
console.log(hasWhitespace(' ')); // space, true
console.log(hasWhitespace(' ')); // tab, true
console.log(hasWhitespace('\r')); // carriage return, true
```

If you don't want to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/), then here is a simple `some` implementation with 2 `s`:

```
const ssome = (predicate, list) =>
{
  const len = list.length;
  for(const i = 0; i<len; i++)
  {
    if(predicate(list[i]) === true) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Then just replace `some` with `ssome`.

```
const hasWhitespace = char => some(
  w => char.indexOf(w) > -1,
  whitespaceCharacters
)
```

For those in Node, use:

```
const { some } = require('lodash/fp');
```

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use **includes()**

```
message :string = "Hello world";
message2 : string = "Helloworld";

message.includes(' '); // true
message2.inlcudes(' ')// false
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach you could take is to compare the length of the original string with that of the string to have whitespaces replaced with nothing. For example:

```
const hasWhiteSpaces = (text: string) => text.length === text.replace(" ", "").length
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.includes(' ')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const checkEmpty = (title: string) => {
    let testString = title.replaceAll(" ", "");

    if (testString.length === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
```

This is what I'm using to check if the input contains just whitespaces
You can also just use the '.includes' operator to check if there are whitespaces included in the string :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggested validation:

```
var isValid = false;

// Check whether this entered value is numeric.
function checkNumeric() {
    var numericVal = document.getElementById("txt_numeric").value;

    if(isNaN(numericVal) || numericVal == "" || numericVal == null || numericVal.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
        alert("Please, enter a numeric value!");
        isValid = false;
    } else {
        isValid = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function containsSpaces(inputString) {
    return /\s/.test(inputString);
}

// Example usage:
console.log(containsSpaces("Hello World")); // Output: true
console.log(containsSpaces("HelloWorld")); // Output: false
console.log(containsWhitespace('hello\tworld')); // Output: true
console.log(containsWhitespace('hello\nworld')); // Output: true
```