# Different behaviour of str.split(' ') in editable divs

Tags: javascript, split, contenteditable

I noticed this "interesting" behaviour. Suppose you have a `<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>`

and you want to get its value (in this case, assume your value is something like 'hello ' (with a trailing whitespace). Afterwars, you want to convert that string into an array using split():

```
var string = window.getSelection().anchorNode.data // hello_ (_ means whitespace)
var myArray = string.split(' ') // ['hello '] -> includes whitespace!
```

However, when you manipulate a string without having to get that value through an editable div, everything works as usual.

Why and how can I force trailing whitespaces to produce another empty value in the resulting array `(['hello', ''])`?

Thanks

Comment: If you have `string = "hello "` then `string.split(" ")` _does_ produce an array with two elements: `["hello", ""]` as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/zgXUp/ - can you reproduce your problem in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of your own?

Comment: Here a "working" example: http://jsfiddle.net/vDDqG/1/. Look at the console. Whitespace is included in myArray.

Comment: @doniyor - I didn't say the delimiter became the array element. Read my comment again - the second array element is an _empty_ string.

Comment: sorry @nnnnnn yeah i got you wrong..

Comment: By the way, you need to add something like "abc " in the editable div. Just in case it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a trailing space from an editable div appears to be character 160 which is a non-breaking space, rather than character 32 which is a "normal" space. You can work around this by splitting on a regex that matches a "normal" space *or* character 160 as follows:

```
var string = window.getSelection().anchorNode.data;
var myArray = string.split(/ |\u00A0/);
console.log(myArray);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zgXUp/2/

Comment: You're welcome. Note that if you enter several trailing spaces in a row it looks like some of them end up as normal spaces and some as non-breaking spaces.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. By the way, what did you use to know the code of that character... something like str.charCodeAt(0)?

Comment: Yeah, I figured what you were seeing wasn't really a space so I used `.charCodeAt()` to confirm - as in the latest version of that demo fiddle...

Answer (score 0):

check before splitting if the string has whitespace, if yes, then split normally and add this into array including the whitespace..

```
...
var splitted;
var array[];
String whitespace = "";
if(string.contains("")){
  splitted = string.split("");
  array.insert(splitted,whitespace);
 }
array.insert(splitted);
```

code is just from my fantasy, i am not coding guru, but is it okay for you?

Comment: Not sure what language you're referring to, but taking your idea, I wasn't able to tell whether a string coming from an editable div contains a whitespace. I used string.indexOf(' ') but it returns false every time.

Comment: my code is just pseudo code, not a working one. look here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731190/javascript-check-if-a-string-has-white-space