# How to find if there is a space in a string... tricky

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing this for a school project but one thing is bugging me, there is a part of the project that requires me to change white space or just " " a space to a number. Here is my code:

I know its messy, I've only been coding for half a year

- `exclsp` is "exclude spaces"
- `inclsp` is "include spaces"
- `dispwos` is "display without spaces"
- `dispwsp` is "display with spaces"

  ```js
  var txt;
  var num;
  var spce = 0;

  function cnt()
  {
      txt = document.getElementById('disp').value;
      num = txt.length;

      // includes spaces into the returned number
      if (document.getElementById("inclsp").checked == true)
      {
          document.getElementById("dispwsp").innerHTML = num + " characters.";
      }

      // excludes spaces from the returned number
      if (document.getElementById("exclsp").checked === true)
      {
          for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
              if (txt.includes(" "))
              {
                  // alert("THERES A SPACE HERE");
                  spce++;
              }
              else
              {
                  num = num;
              }
          } 
      }

      document.getElementById("dispwos").innerHTML = num - spce + " characters.";
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <!doctype html>

  <html>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="LetterCount.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LetterCount.css"/>
   <title>Letter Counter</title>
  </head>

  <body>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Input your text here!" id="disp"></textarea><br>

      <form name="form1">
   <input type="radio"  name="button" id="inclsp"> Include spaces</input><br>
      <input type="radio"  name="button" id="exclsp"> Exclude spaces</input><br>
      </form>

      <button onclick="cnt()">Click Me!</button><br><br>

      <div id="dispwsp"></div>
      <div id="dispwos"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Just so you know there's no such thing as `</input>` in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to change this line:

```
 if (txt.includes(" "))
```

to

```
 if (txt[i] == " ")
```

so that you're actually checking each character rather that attempting to examine the *whole* string each time.
You could also use a regular expression and do it in one simple line of code and eliminate the loop altogether:

```
spce = txt.match(/\s/g).length
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the purpose of the dispwsp dispwos so I just removed them. You only have 1 result you want to display so why put it in different places just make one div for your result, like

```
 <div id="result"></div>
```

And your JS can be simplified a lot, you don't need to loop through the letters. Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zwzqmd27/

```
function cnt() {
  var inputText = document.getElementById("disp").value;
  if (document.getElementById("exclsp").checked) //exclude spaces
  {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = inputText.split(" ").join("").length + " characters";
  } 
  else //include spaces
  {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = inputText.length + " characters";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Check if a string has white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731190/javascript-check-if-a-string-has-white-space)

But you can try this.

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to change a white space in a string to a number..

This could possibly help you ...

```
str.replace(/\s/g,"9");//any number(that You want)
```

This piece of code is basically replaces the white space with a number..

Answer (score 0):

As @Micheal said, you can use ***indexOf()*** method to check if particular character(s) is present in your text content.

You just need to pass the character or substring(set of characters) to check if it is present.

```
Example : 
var myText = "Sample text";
var substringIndex = myText.indexof(" "); //substringIndex = 6
substringIndex = mytext.indexof("ex");//substringIndex  = 8;
substringIndex  = mytext.indexof("tt"); // substringIndex  =-1;
```

If substring doesn't matches, it will return ***-1*** as index.
By using index you can say, if particular character(substring) presents if index value is greater than -1.

Note : If u pass set of characters, it will return only the starting index of the first character if entire set matches.

In your case, it would be like

```
 ...........
   ...........
     if (txt.indexOf(" ")>-1)
        {
            // alert("THERES A SPACE HERE");
            spce++;
        }
        else
        {
            num = num;
        }
      ...............
   ...............
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace script with code bellow..
I do it for you...

```
var txt;
var num;
var spce = 0;

function cnt()
{
//to clear "dispwsp" and "dispwos" before action in cnt() function
document.getElementById("dispwsp").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("dispwos").innerHTML = "";

txt = document.getElementById('disp').value;
num = txt.length;

// includes spaces into the returned number
if (document.getElementById("inclsp").checked == true)
{
    document.getElementById("dispwsp").innerHTML = num + " characters.";
}


// excludes spaces from the returned number
if (document.getElementById("exclsp").checked == true)
{
    num = 0;
    spce = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
        var temp = txt.substring(i, (i+1)); 
            if(temp==" ")
            {
              spce++;
            }else
            {
              num++;
            }
            document.getElementById("dispwos").innerHTML = num  + " characters and "+ spce +" spces ";
        } 
    }   
}
```