# How to detect whitespace in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

how do i detect a whitespace "space" in a string. 
My string are somtehing like this `0651160403XL    00CBD012`

my code:

```
<input type="text" name="myLabel"><br>
<span></span>
<script>
$("input[name='myLabel']").on('keyup', renderInput);
function renderInput() {
input = $(this).val();
if(input.match("/\s+/g"))
//trim the input to 0651160403XL
});
</script>
```

but my code is not working. How can i escape the slash in match function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a string has white space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731190/check-if-a-string-has-white-space)

Comment: May you add example inputs with their expected outputs?

Comment: Use regex without quotes: `input.match(/\s+/g)`

Comment: Maybe something like `if (/\s/.test(input.trim())) { $(this).val(input.trim().split(/\s/)[0]); }`. The question is somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `.replace(/\s+/g,'')`
`

```
$("input[name='myLabel']").on('keyup', renderInput);
function renderInput() {
  input = $(this).val();
  $(this).val(input.replace(/\s+/g,''));
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
input.match(/\s+/g)
```

Or :

```
Var reg = new regex("\\s", "g")
```