# string containing white space or not in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If the string contains white space alert should be unsuccessful and if string contain no white space alert should be successful

```
import React from "react";

export default function DropDown() {
let i=document.getElementById("input")?.value;
const submit=()=>{
  var whiteSpaceExp = /^s+$/g;
  if (whiteSpaceExp.test(i))
  {
  alert('unsuccess');
  }
  else
  {
    alert('success');
  }
  }
return (
    <>
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="input"  autoComplete="off" />
        <button onClick={submit}> click  </button>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string has white space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731190/check-if-a-string-has-white-space)

Comment: yes but when i try var reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("/^\s+$/");
if (reWhiteSpace.test(i)) with this condition its not working

Comment: Take a look [here an example](https://jsfiddle.net/rcj53ops/)

Comment: that's great ,thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/indexOf) method on the input string:

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return s.indexOf(' ') >= 0;
}
```

Or you can use the test method, on a simple RegEx:

```
function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return /\s/g.test(s);
}
```

This will also check for other white space characters like Tab.